# Jquery: mouseover and mouseout strangeness

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document)
    .mouseover(function(event) {  
        if ($(event.target).parents('#myunique').length){ 
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{ 
        $(event.target).addClass('myoutlineElement');
        }
    })
    .mouseout(function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).parents('#myunique').length){  
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{      
        $(event.target).removeClass('myoutlineElement');  
        }
    })
```

I basically have a red border highlight on all elements on a given page (externally loaded via proxy).

Observing through firebug, it seems that addClass is not triggered properly. it adds an empty class (class="") in the given element.

Figured it out. Use .css() instead of addClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.css()` instead of `.addClass()` works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but can you try **hover**?

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$(body).hover(
  function () {
    //do something while mouse over
  }, 
  function () {
    //mouse is out, what now?
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?  **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/auksb/)**

```
$('html>body>*:not(#unique)').hover( function(){
    $(this).addClass('outline');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('outline');
});
```